# check whether the youtube video exists or not in Android YoutubePlayer

Tags: android, youtube-api

I want to check the youtube video exist or not before it is loaded in YoutubePlayer. Is it possible to check whether the youtube video exists or not in Android YoutubePlayer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) to return a videos that match the API request. By doing this, you can now verify if the videoId of the video is existing or not.

Here is the [sample request](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=id&id=kmXXXLBL3Nk&_h=1&).

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id&id=kmXXXLBL3Nk&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Just pass `id` as your part parameter and the `videoId` in the id parameter.

It will return this kind of response if it is existing.

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/ZHvOwtluy6sCNoIMjJVPsNKhBTc\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {


   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/m-PtiixITeo8icgmD0t6X8DGyMA\"",
   "id": "kmXXXLBL3Nk"
  }
 ]
}
```

Now, if the videoId is invalid or not existing your [response](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=id&id=km3424LBL3N&_h=2&) should look like this:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/ZCAnB4VKeQ7X3vzSCnmpxyOQqUk\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 0
 },
 "items": [
 ]
}
```

Hope this information helps you.